# SAS - counting cumulative visits reported

Tags: sql, sas, counting, proc, cumulative-sum

We have a problem with people not submitting hospital visit information in a timely manner. I'm trying to decipher how long (on average) after a visit date a hospital will submit information for all the visits that occured on that date.

Trying to create a table from a current dataset which has 3 relevant fields: Unique_Visiting_ID, Visit_Date, Date_Created, Chief_Complaint.

There can be multiple rows with the same unique_visiting_ID, the unique_visiting_id is the unique identifier for a single patient visit. Visit_date is the date of the visit. The date_created variable tell us the date a a row was sent to us.

The columns on the table I'd like to create are: Days after Visit (0-14) and average number of visits reported on a specific date

For the second column, I'd like to know:
    if I'm limiting date created to 0 days after a visit_date, how many visits (with non-null chief_complaint) occured on a visit date?

if I'm limiting date created to 0 or 1 days after a visit_date, how many visits (with non-null chief_complaint) occured on a visit date?

if I'm limiting date_created to 0, 1 or 2 days after a visit_date, how many visits (with non-null chief_complaint)occurred on that visit date?

etc etc until you get to 1-14 days after a visit_date.

Any ideas? I started off with this, which I know is wrong, but not sure how to fix it...

Comment: Just to clarify, the reason there can be multiple rows with the same `Unique_Visiting_ID` is because of multiple complaints, correct?  That is, any two rows with the same `Unique_Visiting_ID` also have the same `Visit_Date` and same `Date_created`, but different values for `Chief_Complaint`?

Comment: No-- I've only included 4 fields here, because those are the only 4 relevant ones; in reality, I have 64 variables and hospitals can send updates with different values in any of the fields, but the unique_visiting_id will keep them all togehter. That being said, the unique_visiting_ID and visit_date will stay the same, but the date_created (the date that a row was sent) can change, because some information can be sent on the first day and then can be updated on the second day. does that make sense?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I understand it, you really want to produce two tables:

- A list of all visits, with number of days until submission/creation
  for each
- A list of all dates, with number of visits per date, including how many were submitted 0-14 days after

If that is what you meant, this macro should do the trick.  `dsn_in` is the name of your original dataset.  `dsn_out_days` is the name of the dataset holding the results for the first bullet point.  `dsn_out_summary` is the name of the dataset holding the results for the second bullet point.

```
%MACRO do_analysis (dsn_in = , dsn_out_days = , dsn_visits_by_date = );
    %LOCAL i ; 

    DATA &dsn_out_days;
        SET &dsn_in;

        days_after_visit = INTCK ('DAYS', Visit_Date, Date_Created);

        %DO i = 0 %TO 14;
            submitted_up_to_&i._days_after = (days_after_visit <= &i);
            LABEL submitted_up_to_&i._days_after = "Submitted Up To &i Days After" ;
        %END;
    RUN;

    PROC SUMMARY NWAY DATA = &dsn_out_days (
        WHERE = ( NOT MISSING (Chief_Complaint) )
    );
        CLASS Visit_Date;

        OUTPUT 
            OUT = &dsn_visits_by_date (
                DROP = _TYPE_
                RENAME = (_FREQ_ = total_visits) 
            )
            SUM (
                %DO i = 0 %TO 14;
                    submitted_up_to_&i._days_after 
                %END;
            ) =
        ;
    RUN;

    /* Comment out this data step to see how everything works under the hood */
    DATA &dsn_out_days;
        SET &dsn_out_days (
            DROP = 
                %DO i = 0 %TO 14;
                    submitted_up_to_&i._days_after 
                %END;
        );
    RUN;

    DATA &dsn_visits_by_date;
        SET &dsn_visits_by_date ;

        LABEL total_visits = "Total Visits";
    RUN;

    PROC SORT DATA = &dsn_visits_by_date ;
        BY Visit_Date ;
    RUN; 
%MEND;
```

Note that the `%DO` macro usage is there to cut down on the drudgery of typing:

```
submitted_up_to_1_days_after = (days_after_visit <= 1);
submitted_up_to_2_days_after = (days_after_visit <= 2);
submitted_up_to_3_days_after = (days_after_visit <= 3);
. . . .
```

But if you prefer a macro-free solution I can edit.  Just let me know.

Comment: Thanks! Macros make sense to me, so it's fine as it; leaving work now, will try this tomorrow. Thank you so much!!

Comment: Hi...am curious, did it work?  I can try some other stuff if not.

Comment: Sorry, forgot to let you know ages ago that this worked. Thank you so much!!